# Check time is between two times

Tags: c#

I have a todo list in the database. Each Item has a todo item with a time by which it should be completed. What I want to do is have my C# application loop through the items and check if the item should've been completed an hour ago, at tops. Also the application must check if the item should be complete within the hour. If any of these two options is true, the job has to be shown to the user.

How can I make this work? I thought of the way below, but that will show any item that should've been completed an hour ago, or more. I want the items that should've been completed already, with an maximum of 1 hour ago.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsValue.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["tijd"]);

    if (dt > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) || dt < DateTime.Now.AddHours(1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dr["opdracht"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: One quick optimization, you don't want to calculate DateTime.Now.Add(xxx) everytime in the loop

Comment: Why not just change your SQL to use a `BETWEEN` clause?

Comment: @cristobalito If the user needs a long time to dismiss the MessageBox, for whatever reason, he might want to... or not.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - maybe because `BETWEEN` does not capture the requirement as stated?

Comment: @Rowland - My apologies, I misread the question. `BETWEEN` will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would almost work -- you want both conditions to be true, not either, so a quick change to:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsValue.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["tijd"]);

    if (dt > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) && dt < DateTime.Now.AddHours(1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dr["opdracht"].ToString());
    }
}
```

...would suffice. It may be (much) more efficient to move the logic to the database, or at the very least precalculate "an hour ago" and "an hour's time" outside of the loop.

For example, if your SQL looked a s little like

```
DECLARE @HourAgo DATETIME
SET @HourAgo = DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())
DECLARE @HoursTime DATETIME
SET @HoursTime = DATEADD(HOUR,1,GETDATE())
SELECT
    opdracht,
    [other columns]
FROM ExampleTable
WHERE
    opdracht BETWEEN @HourAgo AND @HoursTime
```

Answer (score 0):

if you diff two dates you get a TimeSpan and you can check how many days, hours, minutes and seconds it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that jump out at me...

1. Time comparisons like this are inherently risky. Consider, for example, what happens if the task is created before a daylight savings time switch, and the loop above runs afterwards. Or, if the computer's clock is changed in the interim (maybe the user realizes that it's set wrong). Normalizing times (for example, storing all timestamps as UTC) will help protect against this, but it won't solve the problem completely, particularly if the RTC is changed in the interim.
2. It's generally better to do this sort of data selection in the database than on the client side. Meaning, have the database return a list of "expired" tasks, then work on that client-side.

Comment: 1. I'm building an application for Red Cross dispachers at festivals and so on. The to do Items will all be handled on the same day. So, DST is not really an problem here. But offcource, normaly you would be right.

2. Letting the database handle the task selection is probably a lot better, indeed. Thanks

Comment: MSSQL/.Net/NTFS all store datetime has a 64bit value based on UTC

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
if (dt < DateTime.Now && dt > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
{
    MessageBox.Show(dr["opdracht"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your comparison line should be:

```
if (dt >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) && dt <= DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your data in database using `BETWEEN` operator. Databases were made for this.